# \cite preview displaying RN1-X rather than author and date

Tags: bibtex, natbib

I have a bibliography file generated using Citavi. My preview when using the `\cite` and `\citep` commands only has options like `\cite{RN1}`, `\cite{RN2}` an so on. However, none of these denominators ever appear in the actual bibliography file, therefore `natbib` must generate them. It does show me the correct things like `\cite{Dunn.2002}` when using another Citavi bibtex bibliography generated at a different point in time. I am using the angew citation style. What is causing the incorrect display?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}


 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
 \usepackage[load=abbr , alsoload=synchem]{siunitx}
 \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
 \usepackage[font=small , format =plain , labelfont =bf , up]{caption}
 \usepackage{subfigure}
 \usepackage{nicefrac}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
 \usepackage[absolute , showboxes]{textpos}
 \usepackage{fancybox}
 \usepackage{color}
 \usepackage[usenames ,dvipsnames ,svgnames ,table]{xcolor}
 \usepackage{rotating}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{tabularx}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage{extarrows}
 \usepackage[outdir=./Bilder/]{epstopdf}
 \begin{document}

 \bibliographystyle{angew}
    \bibliography{citavi}           

    \listoffigures

  \end{document}
```

Also: here is an excerpt from the .bib file:

```
 @article{Arstad.2016,
  author = {Arstad, Bj{\o}rnar and Lind, Anna and Cavka, Jasmina H. and           Thorshaug, Knut and Akporiaye, Duncan and Wragg, David and Fjellv{\aa}g, Helmer   and Gr{\o}nvold, Arne and Fuglerud, Terje},
  year = {2016},
  title = {Structural changes in SAPO-34 due to hydrothermal treatment. A    NMR, XRD, and DRIFTS study},
  pages = {421--431},
  volume = {225},
  issn = {13871811},
  journal = {Microporous and Mesoporous Materials},
  doi = {10.1016/j.micromeso.2016.01.024}
 }


 @article{Li.2017,
  author = {Li, Wenze and He, Yingluo and Li, Hangjie and Shen, Dongming and    Xing, Chuang and Yang, Ruiqin},
  year = {2017},
  title = {Spatial confinement effects of zeolite-based micro-capsule      catalyst on tuned Fischer-Tropsch synthesis product distribution},
  pages = {98--101},
 volume = {98},
  issn = {15667367},
  journal = {Catalysis Communications},
  doi = {10.1016/j.catcom.2017.05.008}
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! What preview are you talking about?

Comment: Aside: The `subfigure` package has been deprecated for a long time now. Don’t use it.  Use either `subfig` or `subcaption` instead. And, unless your TeX distribution is positively ancient, there should be no need to load the `epstopdf` package.

Comment: When you begin to type \cite{... there usually is a preview of all available citeable sources in your bibliography file. Instead I see \cite{RN1,2,3,4.. etc. My question is how to get the correct recommendations to show up, since it is really time consuming to constantly look up what the exact label of the bibliography entry is. I am still using subfigure since I am concerned my subcaptions might not be compatible with the formatting of subfig or subcaption

Comment: By preview I mean the autocomplete feature

Comment: Sounds like your are talking about some functionality of your editor. Can you include the name of the editor, so future users with the same problem can find your questions & answer?

Answer (score 1):

Alright I found the problem: I did not actually have the bibliography style file (you have to download it separately and put it the folder, where your original Latex document is in). Seems obvious once you know it!